# Dropdown of Navbar goes behind image slider

Tags: html, css

My dropdown menu goes behind the image slider part of my website. How can I get the dropdown in front of the image slider? I have also some other div's but they go like normally behind the dropdown menu of the Navbar. So I like to have the dropdown in front of the div of the image slider I made. I hope someone can help me

```
<--code html-->
      <nav>
         <div class="logo">
            <div id="myMenu">
            <div class="logo-navbar">
        <nav>
            <a href="index.html"><img src="images/logo-groot.png" height="80" /></a>
        </nav>
        </div>
        </div>
         </div>
    
         <label for="btn" class="icon">
         <span class="fa fa-bars"></span>
         </label>
         <input type="checkbox" id="btn">
         <ul>
            <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
         
            <li>
               <label for="btn-2" class="show">Assortiment</label>
               <a href="#">Assortiment</a>
               <input type="checkbox" id="btn-2">
               <ul>
                  <li><a href="#">Knalvuurwerk</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Siervuurwerk</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Kindervuurwerk</a></li>
                 
               </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
         </ul>
      </nav>
    
     <div class="container">
  <h1 id="headline">Nog <span id="days"></span> dagen tot start online vuurwerkverkoop</h1
  <div id="countdown">

  </div>
</div>
<div class="slideshow-container">

  <!-- Full-width images with number and caption text -->
  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <a href="selectie.html"><img src="images/pyropapel-actie.png" style="width:100%">
   
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <a href="contact.html"><img src="images/logo-groot.png" style="width:100%">
    
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <a href="geschiedenis.html"><img src="images/logo-groot.png" style="width:100%">
    
  </div>

  <!-- Next and previous buttons -->
  <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
  <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>
</div>
<br>

<!-- The dots/circles -->
<div class="dots" style="text-align:center">
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span>
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span>
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span>
</div>
</div>


<-- css -->
nav{
  background: #151515;
}
nav:after{
  content: '';
  clear: both;
  display: table;
}
nav .logo{
  float: left;
  line-height: 70px;
  padding-left: 60px;
}
nav ul{
  float: right;
  margin-right: 4px;
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
}
nav ul li{
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
  background: #151515;
  margin: 5 5px;
}
nav ul li a{
  color: white;
  line-height: 70px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  padding: 8px 15px;
}
nav ul li a:hover{
  color: white;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow:  0 0 5px #000000,
               0 0 10px #0a0a0a;
}
nav ul ul li a:hover{
  box-shadow: none;
}
nav ul ul{
  position: absolute;
  top: 90px;
  border-top: 3px solid red;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  transition: top .3s;
}
nav ul ul ul{
  border-top: none;
}
nav ul li:hover > ul{
  top: 70px;
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}
nav ul ul li{
  position: relative;
  margin: 0px -20px;
  width: 175px;
  float: none;
  display: list-item;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  text-align:center;
}
nav ul ul li a{
  line-height: 50px;
}
nav ul ul ul li{
  position: relative;
  top: -60px;
  left: 150px;
}
.show,.icon,input{
  display: none;
}
.fa-plus{
  font-size: 15px;
  margin-left: 40px;
}
@media all and (max-width: 968px) {
  nav ul{
    margin-right: 0px;
    float: left;
  }
  nav .logo{
    padding-left: 30px;
    width: 100%;
  }
 .show + a, nav > ul{
    display: none;
  }
  nav ul li,nav ul ul li{
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
  }
  nav ul li a:hover{
    box-shadow: none;
  }
  .show{
    display: block;
    color: white;
    font-size: 18px;
    padding: 0 15px;
    line-height: 70px;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  .show:hover{
  color: white;
  border-radius:5px;
 
  }
  .icon{
    display: block;
    color: white;
    position: absolute;
    top: 25;
    right: 40px;
    line-height: 70px;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 25px;
  }
  nav ul ul{
    top: 70px;
    border-top: 0px;
    float: none;
    position: static;
    display: none;
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
  }
  nav ul ul a{
    padding-left: 40px;
  }
  nav ul ul ul a{
    padding-left: 80px;
  }
  nav ul ul ul li{
    position: static;
  }
  [id^=btn]:checked + ul{
    display: block;
  }
  nav ul ul li{
    border-bottom: 0px;
  }
  span.cancel:before{
    content: '\f00d';
  }
}

.slideshow-container {
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
 background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
 width:75%;
}

/* Hide the images by default */
.mySlides {
  display: none;
}

/* Next & previous buttons */
.prev, .next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  align-items: center;
  top: 50%;
  width:auto;
  margin-top: -22px;
  padding: 16px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
  transition: 0.6s ease;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
  user-select: none;

}

/* Position the "next button" to the right */
.next {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}

/* On hover, add a black background color with a little bit see-through */
.prev:hover, .next:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
}

/* Caption text */
.text {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 8px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

/* Number text (1/3 etc) */
.numbertext {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

/* The dots/bullets/indicators */
.dot {
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  margin: 0 2px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
  background-color: #bbb;
}

.active, .dot:hover {
  background-color: #717171;
}

.dots{
 background-color: rgba(23, 14, 13, 0.97);
 width:75%;
 align-items:center;
 margin:auto;
 padding-top: 20px;
 margin-top:-24px;
}
/* Fading animation */
.fade {
  -webkit-animation-name: fade;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
  animation-name: fade;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fade {
  from {opacity: .4}
  to {opacity: 1}
}

@keyframes fade {
  from {opacity: .4}
  to {opacity: 1}
}
```

Comment: try adding z-index: -1 to image. see if it works. add it in media query

Comment: It worked, but now my arrows for the slide next/perv doesn't work anymore

Comment: give them z-index of 1

Comment: I think I putted the z-index -1 wrong. Where should I place it?

Comment: in the class of img which is causing issue. it will make image to appear below

Comment: I did that but the arrows of the slider doesn't work. Also not with z-index:1 or more

Comment: can you please make a jsfiddle file and paste the link. the code above is not well set so its hard to play with it. pictures are not loading. it will help if u do this.